# Centering view with visual format NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to center a view using the visual format language.

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_progressView(300)]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:0 views:views]];
```

(`views` is a `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` containing `_progressView`)

It does not center my view (width: 300) within the `self.view` (width: 768). It aligns it left with an 8 pixel margin, as if I would have only written `@"H:|-[_progressView(300)"`.

Is the only way to center the view using something like:?

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This format string

```
@"H:|-[_progressView(300)]-|"
```

doesn't tell AutoLayout to center `progressView`. Instead it says that `progressView` should be 300 wide and have a system defined standard margin on either side to the superview's edges. Obviously this can't be satisfied, so Auto Layout drops some of the constraints (you probably get some logs on the console). The constraint that is dropped in your case is probably the margin on the right.

To really center a view in it's superview you have to use the verbose constraint method instead of the visual string format, as you already figured out. However, you can easily put that into a nice category like this:

```
@interface UIView (MyLayout)
- (void)centerHorizontallyInSuperview;
@end

@implementation UIView (MyLayout)
- (void)centerHorizontallyInSuperview {
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;
    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                             
                                        toItem:self.superview
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                    multiplier:1 
                                      constant:0];
    [self.superview addConstraint:c];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 18):

Three approaches:

1. You can put your constraint adding code in a method or category as suggested by DrummerB.

   You also, effective iOS 9, can use a newer, more concise syntax, using anchors and using `activateConstraints`:

   ```
   [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
       [centerView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.centerXAnchor],
       ...
   ]];
   ```

   Or in Swift 3:

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       centerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
       ...
   ])
   ```
2. You can use `UILayoutGuide` objects:

   ```
   UILayoutGuide *leftGuide = [[UILayoutGuide alloc] init];
   [view addLayoutGuide:leftGuide];
   UILayoutGuide *rightGuide = [[UILayoutGuide alloc] init];
   [view addLayoutGuide:rightGuide];
   ```

   and define them to be equal to each other with VFL like so:

   ```
   H:|[leftGuide][_progressView(==300)][rightGuide(==leftGuide)]|
   ```

   If you can't use layout guides (e.g. you need to support iOS versions prior to 9.0, you want to create this in IB, etc.) you can use non-visible `UIView` objects (alpha of zero or background color of clear) in a very similar manner. Just add these "spacer" views to your view hierarchy, use horizontal constraints like above, but simply configure the views so you can't see them.

   This technique would be a cumbersome way of solving the "how do a center a view" problem, but is extremely useful if you, for example, want to evenly space a dozen views and you can't use a `UIStackView` for some reason. You can use however many `UILayoutGuide` (or invisible `UIView`) objects that you want in order to achieve the desired effect.
3. For the sake of completeness, I should point out that it's possible to achieve the effect by using `options` of `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX`/`Y`, as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14917695/1271826, but I confess that I find it unnecessarily confusing.

Personally, I think the first approach makes the most sense for your scenario. The second approach is useful when trying to evenly space a bunch of controls, but is too clumsy for this simple scenario. The third approach is an intellectual curiosity, but I wouldn't suggest it in any real-world application.

Comment: Even though I like the category solution best for my current problem, the spacer solution can be very useful when it comes to spacing out multiple items. I up-voted your answer.

Comment: great sumup of the choices. 1. your 2nd. solution is only good if you don't have anything next to centeredView. right? and to create a clearView I should set the alpha of those to `0`? 2. Can you explain waht the `(<=0)` is doing?

Comment: @Honey - No, that second technique works fine if you have anything next to centered view, it's just that you'd probably have separate VFL for the centering of the view and another for placing anything next to it. And, yes, to make a view "clear", just set its background to `clearColor` or reduce its alpha. Or nowadays, you'd generally use `NSLayoutGuide` instead, which is much better. Re the `>=` syntax in third approach, while I originally found that third approach intellectually interesting, in retrospect, I wouldn't advise wasting any time on it. It's horrible pattern.

Answer (score 7):

For those who need it, @DrummerB's ObjC category as Swift extension:

```
extension UIView {

    func centerInSuperview() {
        self.centerHorizontallyInSuperview()
        self.centerVerticallyInSuperview()
    }

    func centerHorizontallyInSuperview(){
        let c: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.superview?.addConstraint(c)
    }

    func centerVerticallyInSuperview(){
        let c: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.superview?.addConstraint(c)
    }

}
```

Comment: I would upvote, but try to reserve that for code that I have tried and know works. So instead I'll just say thank you for posting this.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful and convenient!