# Align view in centre for all device sizes using visual format language (auto layout) programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to align a picker view (pick) in centre of superview(i.e self.view) in all screen sizes.(iphone-4-5-6-6+,ipad-min-air-pro).

i have aligned it in centre in iphone6 using this code

```
pick.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(<=112)-[pick(150)]-(<=112)-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(pick)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(<=258)-[pick(150)]-(<=258)-|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(pick)]];
```

General calculation i did is:-

- Subtract half width/height of subview to half width/height of
  superview.

How to align this view for every screen size without using #define width and height of screen.
Also what calculation you did to obtain the result?
Also i would appreciate if the constraints are set using visual format language.
It should have same alignment for all iOS device screen's.
Thank You..

Comment: Have you seen this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873372/centering-a-view-in-its-superview-using-visual-format-language? Also, do you necessarily need to use VFL? Using a library such as Masonry (https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) would make it dead simple (essentially, one line)

Comment: As mention in the read me file:-
Masonry is in a bugfix only state as more developers will be moving to Swift. Going forward we recommend using SnapKit as it supports Swift and provides better type safety with a simpler API.

Comment: also i have read the link provided, in it a guy(CopperCash) gives a solution to add the view in centre using alignment properties and adding it into dictionary object. but how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using his constraints? His `view` variable is essentialy your `pick` variable.

Comment: Yes,his code is missing something (centreXView/centerYView identifier missing),block NSString unused. So, what to declare as centerX/YView? and where to use the NSString Block